# Find a third-order differential equation with constant coefficients to which the following functions are solutions.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

(I thought for long time but I cannot proceed could anyone give me a hint..)

Find a third-order differential equation with constant coefficients to which the following functions are solutions.

$$
    y_1 (t) = e^{-2t} ,
 y_2 (t) = e^{t} ,
   y_3 (t) = t e^{-2t}
  \qquad\text{ }\quad
$$

Comment: I would start by writing down the derivatives up to order three of each function.

Comment: What are the zeros of the Characteristic Equation? Multiplicities?

Answer (score 1):

Hint, the general solution could be of the form $$y=Ae^{t}+(Bt+C)e^{-2t}$$ so the auxiliary polynomial has a single root at $1$ and a double root at $-2$

Comment: I didn't get your point, could you please explain why is the general solution looks like this or show me the steps please

Comment: The functions you have given are each particular solutions for certain values of $A,B,C$. Write down the polynomial as suggested, and multiply it out. We are just reversing the usual process of solving this type of differential equation...